# node js read file works intermitently

Tags: node.js

I have a simple function to read a file which seems to work intermittently. if you pass in a position it'll read from that position, otherwise it reads the last 10240 bytes. It works most of the time but sometimes it returns with unicode characeters like this.

I cannot figure out why it would fail sometimes, but not all the time.

> "����\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0010|#\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000p=s/�\u0000\u0000�l�\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0

```
var fs = require('fs');
LogReader.prototype.readFile = function(res, position) {
    var path = this.logPath;
    fs.stat(path, function(error, stats) {
        fs.open(path, 'r', function(error, fd) {
            var tell, bufferLength, buffer;
            if (!!position) {
                tell = parseInt(position, 10);

            } else {
                tell = stats.size - 10240;
            }

            bufferLength = stats.size - tell;
            if (bufferLength === 0) {
                res.json({
                    tell: tell,
                    content: ''
                });
                return;
            }

            buffer = new Buffer(bufferLength);

            try {
                fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, bufferLength, tell, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
                    var data = buffer.toString('utf8', 0, buffer.length);

                    res.json({
                        tell: stats.size,
                        content: data.replace(/\r\n/g, '\n')
                    });
                });
            }
            catch(err) {
                // do nothing
            }
            finally {
                fs.close(fd);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Those are NULL bytes. What sort of data are you reading?

Comment: Just a simple text file, a log.